# Suppress "cit." in second reference \footcite using philosophy-verbose

Tags: bibliographies, citing, footnotes, biblatex-philosophy

I am writing my Master Thesis in Humanities and my supervisor is very picky about foot references.

I am using philosophy-verbose and have set it to Italian, and I have reached good results with \footcite.

My problem is, when I have a second reference (not strictly linked to the first, let say that the second reference is some pages below the first), philosophy-verbose gives me "cit." after the title of the work, and I need it not to be shown.

The first reference is fine.
[image]

But when I get to insert the same work some pages below it gives me this:
[image]

that "cit." shouldn't be there, I only need the author-title-pages I used.
I add here the text I am currently working on to test different solutions with a MWE. Please note that I have already had many issues with finding how to put the references in this way and I copied many code segments from other people answers to try and fix the single elements, so there may be some confusion.

I really hope that it is only a minor issue, I am at the very beginning with XeLaTex (and LaTex generally) and sometimes don't fully understand what I'm copying-pasting onto the preamble code.

(If this question has already been asked, I'd be grateful to be addressed to the related post.)

Thanks to everyone in advance from a desperate student.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,latinemph,singletitle=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pretolerance=10000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt



%%%%

%%%%

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %INTERLINEA

%%%%

\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-philosophy} %MAPPING LINGUA





%%%%%

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\italianfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Gentium Plus}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{greek}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false} %NO INDENT PRIMA RIGA DOPO CHAPTER O SECTION


%%%%



%%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}   
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}


\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\iffootnote{\usebibmacro{cite:init}}{}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\global\booltrue{cbx@mlafootnotes}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:mla:foot}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:mla}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{mla:foot:postnote}}

\makeatother


%%%%%%
\bibliography{contratti.bib}

%%%%%

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

%%%%%

\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}    %INDENT PARAGRAFI


%%%%%%
%TOGLIE "" AI TITOLI DI TUTTE LE ENTRY
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}




%%%%%%%

%TOGLIE PARENTESI A DATE
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

%%%%%%

%TOGLIE "P." ALLE PAGINE DI TUTTE LE ENTRY
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{#1}

%%%%%%%



\begin{document}

    This is a citation\footcite[89.]{faraguna1992atene}.
    Now I cite another author\footcite{west1989public}, then the first author but in another work\footcite[89.]{faraguna2011legislazione} and the problematic citation is this\footcite[558.]{faraguna1992atene}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *cit* is inserted by `cite:title` and can be removed by redefining this macro to drop `\bibstring{opcit}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,latinemph,singletitle=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-philosophy}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{greek}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifsingletitle{\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \iftoggle{cbx:commacit}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
      {\setunit{\addspace\midsentence}}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  This is a citation\footcite[89]{knuth:ct:a}.
  Now I cite another author\footcite{worman},
  then the first author but in another work\footcite[89]{knuth:ct:b}
  and the problematic citation is this\footcite[558]{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, TeXbook, 558.]

Note that `biblatex` adds the period at the end of the footnote automatically, so you can just say `\footcite[89]{knuth:ct:a}` instead of `\footcite[89.]{knuth:ct:a}`. If you want to suppress the page prefix "p." you should redefine the field format `postnote` instead (as shown in the MWE, if you get an error due to `\mknormrange`, your `biblatex` is outdated, just use `#1` instead of `\mknormrange{#1}` in that case).

Comment: Thank you very much, I copied the string about cite:title and it just... worked! It was not a major issue as far as I can understand. I did not get the error btw. Thanks again!

Comment: @boten If this answer answered your question, you may want to consider accepting it to mark the issue as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/35864.

Comment: Thanks for this @moewe. I too wanted to suppress the “cit.” when using `philosophy-verbose`. It seems a shame to me that there isn’t a global option to do this. In English language philosophy the verbose style is still very common, and is by far my personal favourite, but the use of “cit.”, “op. cot.”, “loc. cit.” and “ibid.” has gone out of style, it may even be actively discouraged, mostly I think because most people don’t know what they mean. I wonder if Ivan Valbusa might be persuaded to add one.